# talend open studio to extract different csv to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, talend

I have couple of csv file, all of my csv files are about to identical but some columns in csv file are differ from one another. As an example:

csv 1,2,3 have these columns:

```
id name post title cdate mdate path
```

but in csv 4,5 have these columns:

```
id name post title ddate mdate fpath
```

My output should be like this:

```
id name post title cdate mdate ddate path fpath
```

How to achieve this? Currently I am follwoing this:

[image]

But in this procedure I can extract data from csv but not in preferred output..

Comment: is there a way to identify which csv will have path column in them and which will have fpath column...similarly for cdate and mdate columns?

Comment: Yeah.. I can identify that

Answer (score 0):

You need to put each file type in different folder, let's say files 1,2,3 in folder1 and 4,5 in folder 2.

Now, insert files from one folder into you Mongo DB, using this job:

```
tFileList --(iterate)--> tFileInputDelimited --(file_schema)--> tMap ---(DB_schema)--> tMongoDBOutput
```

Here, we use tMap to get DB schema from the file schema, extra columns will remain blanked.

Finally, using a second job which is the same first job but tFileList points to the second folder and tMap have a join between the already written data and the new set of files based on the id, also file schema is different.

```
                                                            tMongoDBInput
                                                                 |
                                                                 |
tFileList --(iterate)--> tFileInputDelimited --(file_schema)--> tMap ---(DB_schema)--> tMongoDBOutput
```

You can use OnSubJobOK to link the first and the second job.